# Flutter FadeInImage fails in Web using kTransparentImage

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-image

I am trying to implement `FadeInImage` like in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) but my App fails with:

> Invalid argument: Unexpected end of image. Request for frame index 0 can't be satisfied.

This is how my `code` looks like:

```
FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  placeholderErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
    print(error);
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  },
  placeholder: kTransparentImage,
  image:
      'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/single-gala-apple-with-leaf-isolated-picture-id1134031619?s=612x612',
),
```

It's pretty much identical to the docs.

I am working with `Flutter Web`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The same thing. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the index.html file and copy-paste the code below in-between the header tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>
```

In my case, this script is working. I hope it will resolve your errors as well.

After pasting this code, kindly stop the browser and restart the whole app. The hot reload and hot restart thing won't work here.

Comment: after adding this all my texts have a different style and most of my other images are cut off. Doesn't feel right

Comment: Could you provide some more information on what's happening and some screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

you must miss the following code:
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';